Creating Standalone Service Fabric Cluster without being admin on all the nodes
I am trying to create a Standalone Service fabric cluster according to this. From the environment setup, I understand that the user creating the cluster should have administrator-level security privileges to all machines that are listed as nodes in the cluster configuration file.
Is there a way I can bypass this? I want to create SF cluster with Windows server 2022 datacenter VMs where I cannot be the admin of other nodes or Is there a way to add a user as admin in other machine, is it allowed?
Without being admin, I am getting the RemoteRegistryAvailable : False while running TestConfiguration script
Running SF runtime : 10.1.1951.9590

Administrator-level privileges are required to create a standalone Service Fabric cluster, as certain operations like opening the remote registry service need these permissions. If you’re seeing RemoteRegistryAvailable: False, it indicates that these permissions are not available. Unfortunately, there’s no workaround to bypass this requirement. @Prabhu
